# Do loop parameters considered as non-numeric characters

Tags: fortran, mex

I am a Newbie to Fortran, facing a problem within a Do loop. I am programming a Fortran Code for a MEX File to be used within Matlab. 
I assume it has a problem with the definition of k and z, but I don't see why. Maybe you guys have a hint for me what I am doing wrong. Thank you very much!

*Error Message and Code
    innerloops.F
    do k = 1, 4

    1
    Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
    innerloops.F
    do k = 1, 4

    1
    Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
    innerloops.F
    do z = 1, 25

    1
    Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
    innerloops.F
    do z = 1, 25

    Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)*

```
C     Computational routine
subroutine innerloops(J,c1,c2,c3,c4,n1,n2,n3,n4,y,m,n)
mwSize m, n
integer k, z
real*8 J(m,n), y(4,1), c1, c2, c3, c4, n1, n2, n3, n4
real*8 QuadRuleX(25,2)
real*8 QuadRuleW(25,1)
real*8 X(5,1), r, t
real*8 P, c_h, n_h
integer h = 10 

C     Gaussian Points
X(1) = -.906179
X(2) = -.538469
X(3) = 0
X(4) = .538469
X(5) = .906179

C     Corresponding QuadRule points
QuadRuleX(1,1) = X(1)
QuadRuleX(1,2) = X(1)
C .... (snipped it here for readability)

C Corresponding weights
QuadRuleW(1) = Y(1)*Y(1)
QuadRuleW(2) = Y(2)*Y(1)
C .... (snipped it here for readability)

do k = 1, 4           
do z = 1, 25
r = QuadRuleX(z,1)
t = QuadRuleX(z,2)
P = shape(k,r,t)
c_h = c1*shape(k,r,t)
n_h = n1*shape(k,r,t)
y(k,1) = (P*((((h-1)*c_h)/(h-1)*c_h+1))*n_h*(2-n_h)-n_h)
continue
continue
return
end do
end subroutine innerloops

C defining the shape functions
Function shape(q,c,d)
implicit none
real q,c,d,P 
if (q == 1) then
P = 1/4*(c-1)*(d-1)
else if (q == 2) then
P = -1/4*(c+1)*(d-1)
else if (q == 3) then
P = 1/4*(c+1)*(d+1) 
else if (q == 4) then
P = -1/4*(c-1)*(d+1)
endif
return
end Function shape
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing an "end do" for `do k = 1, 4` .

Comment: Yes.  You probably want `end do` instead of each of the `continue` statements.  And then remove the `end do` after the `return` statement -- it is inaccessible.  Indenting would make your code more readable.

Comment: not the cause of you error but be aware integer division 1/4 yields zero. best make that 1./4. ..

Comment: Since you are a newbie, I would highly recommend you to leave FORTRAN 77 and use fortran 90+. It has so many helpful features you will start loving very soon. One of the obvious is `implicit none`,  you will recognise its power once you start writing a medium size (>300 line may be) program. 
As Zhu stated, you would have been safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a .F suffix the compiler by default assumes that you are using a fixed format source code.  In fixed format certain columns are reserved for special purposes.  Here it appears that your "do" has been mistakenly put into a column reserved for statement label (columns 1 through 5). Your statement has to fit between column 7 and 72 in a fixed-format fortran file.  This is what the compiler was complaining about.  As mentioned by others, your code also contain other errors that need to be fixed.

To make things simpler, you can use a free format instead by changing the suffix to .f90 and replacing the "C" comment indicator with "!".